# Can't redirect rfcomm output to a file

Tags: bash, output, rfcomm

I would like to redirect the output of `rfcomm` to a file in bash like

```
$ rfcomm watch hci0 > rfcomm.log &
```

or

```
$ rfcomm watch hci0 > rfcomm.log 2>&1 &
```

However `rfcomm.log` remains desparately empty.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure `rfcomm watch hci0` produces output on `stdout`?

Comment: I am only aware of `stdout` and `stderr` and `rfcomm` does print out some stuff at the command line so I guess it sends it to `stdout`, right?

Comment: What happens if you do, `rfcomm watch hci0 > rfcomm.log`? Are you seeing entries in log

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all.

Comment: Me too. `rfcomm watch hci0` prints `Waiting for connection on channel 1` but if redirected nothing gets outputed to screen or file.

Comment: The `strace` logs are different if `rfcomm` output is redirected. When redirected the `write(1, "Waiting for connection on channel 1") = 36` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If this program is writing to the tty directly then you can capture the output by invoking it via `ssh` with a pseudo-tty (`-t`). Try:

```
ssh -t localhost 'rfcomm watch hci0' > rfcomm.log
```